# Pleiadesに内蔵されているMavenの位置はどこ？

Tags: eclipse, maven

mvnビルド時、JREを正しく認識できないので、調査のためにPleiadesにEMBEDDEDされているMavenをコマンドラインで実行してみたい。内蔵されているMaven EXEの位置はどこですか？ eclipseのディレクトリ内で「maven」、「mvn」を検索しても見つかりません。

Answer (score 2):

Pleiades ではないですが、私の環境である Eclipse2019-06(4.12)相当では

```
/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.12.0.20190628-1133
```

にあります。ネイティブバイナリではないのでexeはありません(し、スタンドアロンのMavenパッケージと異なり起動用のスクリプトもありません)。

ディレクトリやファイル名には maven という名前がついているので、正常な状態であれば検索でヒットするかと思います。

---

mainクラスは、[スタンドアロン版のコード](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.6.1/apache-maven/src/bin/m2.conf#L1)を参照すれば判明しますが、 `maven-embedder*.jar`の[`org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.6.1/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java)です。

なので、例えば私の環境だと次のようなコマンドで起動はできます。

```
$ pwd
[ECLIPSE_ROOT]/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.12.0.20190628-1133

$ java -cp "../org.slf4j.api_1.7.10.v20170428-1633.jar:jars/*" org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli
```

ただし、これだけだとシステムプロパティ未設定なのでエラー終了します。
このあと、正常終了させたいのであれば、[起動スクリプト](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.6.1/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn)から設定すべき起動引数を探っていくことになるでしょう。

Comment: @起動できないですね。javaの入り口クラスはないでしょうか？